# Maintaining a single, persistent EM connection in a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, eventmachine

I'm a bit of an EventMachine novice, so there's a chance I'm approaching this completely wrong. What I'm trying to do is create an EM connection (actually a Blather stream, but that is an EM::Connection) once when the app starts up, which I can then hit whenever I need to. Right now, the only way I can Blather to work correctly in this Sinatra app is to create a new connection every time, which is wrapped inside a EM.run block.

I've been trying to determine if async_sinatra would help. I don't actually care, though, if the requests happen asynchronously. I suppose it would be nice, but I'm still not seeing how I would persist the connection between requests.

The solution that seems to make the most sense in my brain is to setup the connection in an EM block inside the Sinatra configure block, but then I'm not sure how to get access to it down the road. Perhaps I'm missing something kind of basic, though.

p.s. This will eventually run on Heroku, so while I would greatly appreciate any insight, solutions that are known to work on Heroku will be the most useful.

Edit:

This seems to be doing what I want, locally at least:

```
class Dashboard < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    Thread.start do
      EM.run do
        @@xmpp_stream = Blather::Client.setup('jid', 'password')
        @@xmpp_stream.connect
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How are you going to run the application ? If you use multiple workers you will get one connection for each worker, is it a problem ?

Comment: When you deploy the app, don't forget to use the Cedar stack, as EventMachine is only supported on that stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to start with:

```
require 'rack'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'eventmachine'

class EMHandler < EM::Connection
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
    @data = ""
  end

  def receive_data(data)
    @data << data
  end
end

class PersistentConnection
  def initialize(app, options = {})
    @app = app
    EM::next_tick do
      @server = EM::connect('127.0.0.1', 4000, EMHandler, self)
    end
  end

  def call(env)
    env['my_connection'] = @server
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

class Dashboard < Sinatra::Base
 get '/' do
   env['my_connection'].data
 end
end

use PersistentConnection
run Dashboard
```

This will open a persistent connection to a server on localhost with port 4000, it will store anything received from it and displays it when the index page is requested via a web browser.

Save this in a "config.ru" file and run this with:

```
$ thin start -V
```

In my case the server on port 4000 was (I am on mac os x, linux also has it):

```
$ nc -l 4000
```

Just replace the connection I open with what you want.